# How do I correct this flutter error: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I send data from flutter to php I am getting the error below. I am using dropdown and map to display and collect the date selection. I also have a few text boxes
Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50857/dart_sdk.js:5334:11)

```
Future _submitemail() async {
  var apiUrl = "http://www.redhowler.com/db/signup.php";

 String date = year +'-'+ month +'-'+ day;
 print(date);
  Map mappedData = {
   'email': _email.text,
   'date': date
  };
  http.Response response = await http.post(apiUrl, body: mappedData);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data);
}
}
```

Comment: What's in `response.body`? Are you sure it does not contain malformed JSON or even empty?

Comment: @Agrgg The author of the question probably thinks that we already know what the reason is without additional information. How can you ask questions like that? Are we telepathic here or what? Probably, the author does not even know what a token is.

Comment: Agrgg and menzoni. Not sure what you asking. The code worked fine if you pass in all textfield( e.g _email.text, name.text) . I added a dropdown and got his error. Which token is giving the error? Is it the way I selected or format the date or is it the way I echo the result back?

Comment: @Agrgg i am getting the same error, in my case, it only happened if it returns an empty list and the funny thing is it happens when i use https but it working fine with http. my code looks like:          ```uri = (APIPROTOCOL == 'http://')
        ? Uri.http(APIHOST, '/api/commitments/', uriQuery)
        : Uri.https(APIHOST, '$APIHOST_PREFIX/api/commitments/', uriQuery);```.  Now, I have two servers, one is running with http other one https, i got the error only with https, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Davood Have you check the request in Postman or any other similar tool? It probably happens, because pure HTTP call returns you a valid JSON. But because you've misconfigured HTTPS, when you send an HTTPS request the server cannot process it and returns a non-JSON response. Usually an HTTP error with empty body on even some kind of default HTML page (which is obviously considered as malformed JSON).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I format the body data the way it is display on the form. I capture date first, then email. So I changed the mappedData. Look at the code when I first post the problem compare to the code below.

```
Future _submitemail() async {
  var apiUrl = "http://www.redhowler.com/db/signup.php";

 String date = year +'-'+ month +'-'+ day;
 print(date);
  Map mappedData = {
   'date': date,
   'email': _email.text
  };
  http.Response response = await http.post(apiUrl, body: mappedData);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data);
}
}
```